# Why the first time memory copy runs is slow?

Tags: performance, caching, go, io, cpu-cache

What I found:

I print the time cost of golang's copy, and it shows the first time of memory copy is slow. But the second time is much faster even I run "copy" on different memory address.

Here is my test codes:

```
func TestCopyLoop1x32M(t *testing.T) {
    copyLoopSameDst(32*1024*1024, 1)
}
func TestCopyLoopOnex32M(t *testing.T) {
    copyLoopSameDst(32*1024*1024, 1)
}
func copyLoopSameDst(size, loops int) {
    in := make([]byte, size)
    out := make([]byte, size)
    rand.Seed(0)
    fillRandom(in) // insert random byte into slice
    now := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < loops; i++ {
        copy(out, in)
    }
    cost := time.Since(now)
    fmt.Println(cost.Seconds() / float64(loops))
   }

func TestCopyDiffLoop1x32M(t *testing.T) {
    copyLoopDiffDst(32*1024*1024, 1)
}

func copyLoopDiffDst(size, loops int) {
    ins := make([][]byte, loops)
    outs := make([][]byte, loops)
    for i := 0; i < loops; i++ {
        out := make([]byte, size)
        outs[i] = out
        in := make([]byte, size)
        rand.Seed(0)
        fillRandom(in)
        ins[i] = in
    }

    now := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < loops; i++ {
        copy(outs[i], ins[i])
    }
    cost := time.Since(now)
    fmt.Println(cost.Seconds() / float64(loops))
}
```

The Result(on a i5-4278U):

1. Run all the three case:

TestCopyLoop1x32M    : 0.023s

TestCopyLoopOnex32M   : 0.0038s

TestCopyDiffLoop1x32M   : 0.0038s

2. Run first&second case:

TestCopyLoop1x32M    : 0.023s

TestCopyLoopOnex32M   : 0.0038s

3. Run first&third case:

TestCopyLoop1x32M    : 0.023s

TestCopyLoop1x32M   : 0.023s

My questions:

1. They have different memory address and different data, how could the next case get benefit from the first one?
2. Why the Result3 is not same as Result2? Don't they do the same thing?
3. If I add the loop in "copyLoopSameDst", I know the next time will be faster because the cache, but my cpu's L3 Cache is only 3MB, I can't explain the huge improvement
4. Why "copyLoopDiffDst" will speed up after two case?

My guess:

1. the instruction cache help to improve performance, but it can't explain question2
2. the cpu cache works beyond my imagination, but it can't explain question2 either

Comment: I don't know anything about go, but if you are dynamically creating and freeing in/out inside the function, its likely that the by the time second function wants to write data, they are already in the cache. If you want to test if this is the case, try creating 2 different in/out globally, for both functions. In this way the second function would not have the above advantage, you should see a slowdown

Comment: thank you! After I moved the data out of test function, as what you said, it slowdown. But in my codes, "TestCopyLoop1x32M" & "TestCopyLoopOnex32M" do the same thing, why only the second one will have cache? Both of them create new data on new memory address, doesn't it?

Comment: @IsuruH thank you for your idea. I think I have found the answer, but the cache's power really impress me. Just a few of data can have write hit, but it improve performance so much

Answer (score 0):

After more research and testing, I think I can answer part of my questions.

The reason of cache works in next test case is Golang's (maybe other languages will do same things, because malloc memory is a system call) memory allocation.

When the data is big, kernel will reuse the block which just been freed.

I print the in&out []byte's address(in Golang, the first 8bytes of a slice is it's memory address, so I write a assembly to get the address):

addr: [0 192 8 32 196 0 0 0] [0 192 8 34 196 0 0 0]

cost: 0.019228028

addr: [0 192 8 36 196 0 0 0] [0 192 8 32 196 0 0 0]

cost: 0.003770281

addr: [0 192 8 34 196 0 0 0] [0 192 8 32 196 0 0 0]

cost: 0.003806502

You will find program reusing some memory address, so write hit happen in the next copy action.

If I create in/out out of function, the reusing will not happen, and it slow down.

But if you set the block very small (for example, under 32KB) You will find the speeding up again although kernel give your a new memory address. In my opinion the main reason is the data is not aligned by 64bytes, so the next loop data (its location is nearby the first one) will be caught into cache, at the same time, the first loop waster much time for fill cache. And the next loop can get the instruction cache and other data cache for run the function. When the data is small, these little cache will make big influence.

I still feel amazed, the data size is 10x of my cpu cache size, but the cache still can help a lot. Anyway, it's another question.